# Не подключается файл php к сайту

Tags: php, html

Файл php открывается просто белым листом. На других страницах php всё отображается корректно.

```
<? 

$Page['title'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['description'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['keywrods'] = 'Выбрать дом';

$Page['html'] = '
<div class="inner">
    <div class="main_map"></div>
    <div class="main_sale_count">61<br><br>объект<br>в продажу</div>
    <a href="/" class="main_logo"></a>
    <a href="booklet.pdf" target="_blank" class="main_download_buklet">Скачать буклет</a>
    <div class="main_contacts">
        <div>8 (921) 558 70 52</div>

        <button onclick="showCallme();">Заказать звонок</button>

 </div>

    <h1 class="main">
    <center>
<table border="1" width="30%" height="100">

    <tr>
 <br>
    <td><a href=""houses.php"align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Таунхаусы</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Коттеджи</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Квартиры</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Апартаменты</a></td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</center>
</h1>

    <br><br><br>

    <div class="p_text" style="padding: 300px 30px 0 30px;">

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/1facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 1</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 226 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house1" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/2facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 2</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 143,70 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house2" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div style="height: 2px; background: #c6c6c6; margin: 20px 0;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/3facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 3</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 212 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house3" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>

                <td width="20%"><img src="images/4facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 4</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 234,60 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house4" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div style="height: 2px; background: #c6c6c6; margin: 20px 0;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/5facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 5</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 238 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house5" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/6facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 6</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 187 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house6" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
';
```

> Прикрепить всё надо к файлу ниже в раздел "таунхаусы". Подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

```
<?php

$Page['title'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['description'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['keywrods'] = 'Выбрать дом';

$Page['html'] = '
<div class="inner">
    <div class="main_map"></div>
    <div class="main_sale_count">61<br><br>объект<br>в продажу</div>
    <a href="/" class="main_logo"></a>
    <a href="booklet.pdf" target="_blank" class="main_download_buklet">Скачать буклет</a>
    <div class="main_contacts">
        <div>8 (921) 558 70 52</div>

        <button onclick="showCallme();">Заказать звонок</button>

 </div>

    <h1 class="main">
    <center>
<table border="1" width="30%" height="100">

    <tr>
 <br>
    <td><a href="townhouses.php""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Таунхаусы</a></td>
    <td><a href=""townhouses.php"align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Коттеджи</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Квартиры</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Апартаменты</a></td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</center>
</h1>

    <br><br><br>


    <div class="p_text" style="padding: {1,1};">

    <iframe src="map.php" width="1056" height="523" align=top scrolling="no" frameborder="0" > </iframe>



    </div>
</div>
';
```

Comment: Логи ошибок апача в студию. Экстрасенсы в отпуске

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос. Где хранятся логи если сайт залит на timeweb?

Comment: `/var/log/apache2` В любом случае в `/var/log/...`

Comment: Я вижу присвоения, но не вижу вывода.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно я не правильно понял вопрос, но из того, как я понял. Этот файл ничего не выводит на странице, но он и не должен, у вас же нет никакого вывода. Вы просто поместили данные в массив и если вы напишете `print_r($Page)`, то вы увидете весь ваш код в массиве.

**UPD:** Если вам нужно вывести просто одну из переменных, то это можно сделать таким образом `echo $Page['html'];`

Comment: а что надо прописать или добавить,что бы страница стала нормально отображаться?

Comment: `echo` к простой переменной, если нужно весь массив, то `print_r`. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Наверное `?>` надо добавить вконце?

Comment: Добавлял, тоже самое происходит.

Comment: @Sergey на хостинге запустить `php /путь/до/скрипта.php` что пишет?

Comment: 1 ошибка. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Если весь файл состоит из PHP кода, то `?>` необязателен

Comment: Если я это же файл переименовываю в html, он начинает работать, но без шапки и подвала, также не подключаются стили.

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто присвоили элементу массива значение, нужно ввести.

```
$Page['title'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['description'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['keywrods'] = 'Выбрать дом';

echo $Page['html'] = '
<div class="inner">
    <div class="main_map"></div>
    <div class="main_sale_count">61<br><br>объект<br>в продажу</div>
    <a href="/" class="main_logo"></a>
    <a href="booklet.pdf" target="_blank" class="main_download_buklet">Скачать буклет</a>
    <div class="main_contacts">
        <div>8 (921) 558 70 52</div>

        <button onclick="showCallme();">Заказать звонок</button>

 </div>

    <h1 class="main">
    <center>
<table border="1" width="30%" height="100">

    <tr>
 <br>
    <td><a href=""houses.php"align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Таунхаусы</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Коттеджи</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Квартиры</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Апартаменты</a></td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</center>
</h1>

    <br><br><br>

    <div class="p_text" style="padding: 300px 30px 0 30px;">

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/1facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 1</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 226 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house1" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/2facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 2</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 143,70 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house2" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div style="height: 2px; background: #c6c6c6; margin: 20px 0;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/3facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 3</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 212 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house3" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>

                <td width="20%"><img src="images/4facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 4</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 234,60 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house4" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div style="height: 2px; background: #c6c6c6; margin: 20px 0;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/5facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 5</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 238 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house5" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/6facad.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 6</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 187 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="house6" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
';
```

Comment: я так понимаю это как раз то что нужно, а можно немножко по подробнее? Куда и что я не ввёл?

Comment: Вы должны были вывести переменную, а в вашем примере просто присвоили ей значение.

Comment: Теперь страница отображается(за это спасибо)), но без стилей. Может вы подскажите как и стили подключить? Они здесь не прописаны. есть файл style.css, но по средствам чего он подключён не очень понятно. На всех страницах стили отображаются корректно(фон, шапка, подвал).